# Detecting whether application crashed in Windows

Tags: windows, crash

In Windows, is there any way to probe a process to ascertain whether it has crashed or not ? Is there any way to know that the process has received a SIGSEV signal ?

Comment: Windows doesn't have POSIX signals.

Comment: I think Procdump will go quote a long way to show you what's available on Windows regarding capturing hangs and crashes from a user mode process - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx